# Using npm package ssh2 within an Angular2 application running under electron

Tags: node.js, angular, ssh, npm, angular-services

I want to create an Angular2 service which uses the npm package ssh2 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2.

I have installed and configured it as I would expect - the code for my service can be seen below (this code is based on the first example shown on the ssh2 npm site and github repo(the only change being I am using a password rather than a key for authentication)):

```
const Client = require('ssh2').Client;
const fs = require('fs');

import { NextObserver } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

export class SSHClient {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    host: string;
    port: number;
    ssh: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    init(username, password, host, port) {
        console.log("initiating SSH connection to:" + host + "on port:" + port);

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;


        console.log("Connecting now...");
        var conn = new Client();
        conn.on('ready', function() {
          console.log('Client :: ready');
          conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
              console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
              conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
              console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
          });
        }).connect({
          host: this.host,
          port: this.port,
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        });
        console.log("SSH Client created and demo has run");
    }

}
```

I make my call to the service as per this from within my component:

```
this.ssh.init("username","password","my.little.host",22);
```

And I expect to get back the output of the uptime command having executed over SSH on my server - via the console. However instead of that - I get this:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ServerBrowserComponent class ServerBrowserComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at SSHClient.init (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:40259:12)
    at new ServerBrowserComponent (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:34158:19)
    at new Wrapper_ServerBrowserComponent (/AppModule/ServerBrowserComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
    at DebugAppView._View_ServerBrowserComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/ServerBrowserComponent/host.ngfactory.js:16:38)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:27754:26)
    at DebugAppView.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:27954:49)
    at ComponentFactory.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:24393:41)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:23441:50)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:72709:45)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:72207:21)
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ServerBrowserComponent class ServerBrowserComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at SSHClient.init (ssh.service.ts:49)
    at new ServerBrowserComponent (server.browser.component.ts:31)
    at new Wrapper_ServerBrowserComponent (wrapper.ngfactory.js:7)
    at DebugAppView._View_ServerBrowserComponent_Host0.createInternal (host.ngfactory.js:16)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (core.umd.js:9170)
    at DebugAppView.create (core.umd.js:9370)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.umd.js:5809)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (core.umd.js:4857)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (router.umd.js:3457)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (router.umd.js:2955)
    at resolvePromise (zone-node.js:468)
    at zone-node.js:445
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-node.js:232)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.umd.js:6206)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-node.js:231)
    at Zone.run (zone-node.js:114)
    at zone-node.js:502
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-node.js:265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6197)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-node.js:264)
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in ./ServerBrowserComponent class ServerBrowserComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ViewWrappedError TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at SSHClient.init (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:40259:12)
    at new ServerBrowserComponent (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:34158:19)
    at new Wrapper_ServerBrowserComponent (/AppModule/ServerBrowserComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
    at DebugAppView._View_ServerBrowserComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/ServerBrowserComponent/host.ngfactory.js:16:38)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:27754:26)
    at DebugAppView.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:27954:49)
    at ComponentFactory.create (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:24393:41)
    at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:23441:50)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:72709:45)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (file:///Users/myapp/build/app.js:72207:21)
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./ServerBrowserComponent class ServerBrowserComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined(…)
```

The bulk of that seems to be struggling because : `Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined` -- yet I am following the example documentation. Can somebody please help my understand why this is not working - and how I can fix it?

I tried to pull the code out of my project and into its own file which looks like:

```
    const Client = require('ssh2').Client; 
console.log("Connecting now...");
         var conn = new Client();
         conn.on('ready', function() {
          console.log('Client :: ready');
          conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.on('close', function(code, signal) {
                 console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
                  conn.end();
            }).on('data', function(data) {
                  console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
            }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                  console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
            });
          });
       }).connect({
          host: 'my.little.host',
          port: 22,
          username: 'uname',
          password: 'pwd'
        });
         console.log("SSH Client created and demo has run");
```

But I get the same error:

```
 var conn = new Client();
                ^

ReferenceError: Client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/myapp/attempt.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at run (node.js:348:7)
    at startup (node.js:140:9)
    at node.js:463:3
```

So something simple is going wrong here, what could it be!?

Comment: What version of `ssh2` do you have installed?

Comment: "ssh2": "^0.5.4",

Comment: Does the same `ssh2` code work if you just test it by itself (without the class, export, etc.)?

Comment: Acutally no - i get exactly the same error - see the updated question above

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `const Client = require('ssh2').Client` line.

Comment: That was a typo as I miss copy pasted! It's there!

Comment: Actually sorry - on its own it does work, i had missed that line, so why doesn't it work in my other setup?

Comment: Could be due to Electron's design, I don't know. Did you try using your original code, but move the `const Client = require('ssh2').Client` line right before you call `new Client()`?

Comment: Yeah tried that too - resulted in the same error.

Comment: mscdex - do you see the suggested solution below somehow being able to be incorporated into Angular2?

Answer (score 3):

the ssh2-package is for node.js, not frontend/web.

The browser can't use network like that (electron uses two processes, the browser/renderer -process does not have access to the network features you need)

does your electron app have a main.js file?

that's where you need to implement the ssh functionality.

i.e. in the main-process, not in the renderer-process.

http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/#main-process

Comment: So the process objects have access to http etc but not ssh?

Comment: Yes, the renderer is essentially a chrome browser, you can't do ssh in chrome so you can't do it here either

Comment: Ahah ok,  I'll try this and use renderer ipc to go back and forwards between the client and server side!

Comment: no, with node integration, you can pretty much do anything in renderer like in node env, i have implemented a ssh client with ssh2 in renderer

Answer (score -1):

In my wrapper of ssh2 (ssh2shell) I have `this.connection = new require('ssh2')();` within the constructor of the class or it could be put in the init function. Creating it within the instance might help.

```
"use strict";

class SSHClient {
    constructor() {}

    init(username, password, host, port) {
        console.log("initiating SSH connection to:" + host + "on port:" + port);
        var ssh = require('ssh2').Client
        this._conn = new ssh();

        console.log("Connecting");

        console.log('Client :: ready');
        var self = this
        this._conn.on('ready', function() {
            self._conn.exec('uptime', function(err, stream) {
                if (err) throw err;

                stream.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('STDOUT: ' + data);
                }).stderr.on('data', function(data) {
                    console.log('STDERR: ' + data);
                }).on('close', function(code, signal) {
                    console.log('Stream :: close :: code: ' + code + ', signal: ' + signal);
                    self._conn.end();
                });
            });
        }).connect({
            host: host,
            port: port,
            username: username,
            password: password
        });

        console.log("SSH Client created and demo has run");
    }
}
module.exports = SSHClient
```

Or using my [package ssh2shell](https://github.com/cmp-202/ssh2shell) the ssh connection instance is within the sope of ssh2shell instance so you don't have to worry about it.

```
"use strict";

class SSHClient {
    constructor() {}

    init(username, password, host, port) {
        console.log("initiating SSH connection to:" + host + "on port:" + port);

        var host = {
            server: {     
                host:         host,
                port:         port,
                userName:     username,
                password:     password
                },
            commands:      [ "uptime" ]
        }

        var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell'),

            //Use a callback function to handle the response text
            callback = function(sessionText){
                console.log("SSH Client created and demo has run");
                console.log("Response:\n" + sessionText)
            }

        //Create a new instance passing in the host object
        this._conn = new SSH2Shell(host)

        //Start the process
        this._conn.connect(callback);
    }
}

module.exports = SSHClient
```

Comment: On your first suggestion I get the error :

 Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.

On the 'this._conn = new require('ssh2')();' line -- I also think you have a couple typos this_conn instead of this._conn. Either way it won't compile my typescript.

When I try your second example I get compilation errors - please see this gist:https://gist.github.com/renegadeandy/85930e0ce06cf02612f298d0615927f8 -- note the warning doesn't look healthy here?

Comment: I will drop it into a test file and see what I get.

Comment: examples updated with code that works on my test environment. Export class didn't work for me, I fixed typos and {} error in host object. I had some of those undefined errors but I can't see in your examples in either the orriginal code or the test you seperated out why it was undefined which isn't helpful. One option would be to console.log the Client and conn variables to see what returns.

Comment: So from your example how would I consume this and expose via a service or in a way I can use in a component in angular? Ideally it needs wrappered by a service

Comment: Is this a new question?

Comment: I wouldn't call it one - as my original goal is using an SSH client from an angular2 service!

Comment: My expertise is the SSH component of your question to resolve why it wasn't working which hopefully it is now. Someone else will have to provide the angular service bit.